# Grouping values of a dictionary together in Python

Tags: python

I have a dictionary as follows:

```
comb_dict = 
['1d812hjbsa' : ['Apple', 'iPad'], '190usdnb1' : ['Amazon', 'Kindle'], 'sjdb1892': ['Apple', 'iPad'], '23ub8wh12' : ['Apple', 'iPhone'], '12ndsi01' : ['Amazon', 'Kindle'] ]
```

The key is the transaction id and the values are the company and the product name. I'm trying to group then Company and Product together and take a count. For this example, I'm expecting an output as follows:

```
fin_dict=
[ ['Apple', 'iPad'] : 2, '['Amazon', 'Kindle'] : 2, ['Apple', 'iPhone', : 1 ]
```

I tried to read the data into a new dictionary with the key-value reversed from the input. But, it's not working as I expected and throwing the following error:

```
for key, value in comb_dict.items():
    if fin_dict.has_key(value):
        fin_dict[value] +=1
    else:
        fin_dict.update({value : 1})
```

**`Output`**

```
   if fin_dict.has_key(value):
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Can someone point out how to fix this?

Thanks,
TM

Comment: your comb_dict is not a dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your dictionary keys cannot be lists, because a list is mutable. You need a tuple or other immutable object.

I would suggest you instead do this using a Counter.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> dic = {'1d812hjbsa' : ['Apple', 'iPad'], '190usdnb1' : ['Amazon', 'Kindle'], 'sjdb1892': ['Apple', 'iPad'], '23ub8wh12' : ['Apple', 'iPhone'], '12ndsi01' : ['Amazon', 'Kindle']}
>>> counter = Counter(tuple(v) for v in dic.values())
>>> dict(counter)
{('Amazon', 'Kindle'): 2, ('Apple', 'iPad'): 2, ('Apple', 'iPhone'): 1}
```

Additionally, do not use `has_key()`, which is deprecated. Instead, use the `in` keyword. For example, `if value in fin_dict:`.

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you what's going wrong: you can't use a list as a dictionary key, because a list isn't hashable.

Luckily you can convert it to a tuple, which is hashable. Note that there is a nice class which already does the counting for you, in `collections.Counter`.

```
import collections
fin = collections.Counter(tuple(i) for i in comb.values())
```

Comment: Pretty lame from my part...forgot about counters completely...thank you...:-)

Answer (score 0):

Error occurs because list is unhashable. For example, you can convert lists to comma separated strings:

```
fin_dict = {}

for t in comb_dict:
    hash = ",".join(comb_dict[t])
    if not fin_dict.has_key(hash):
        fin_dict[hash] = 1
    else:
       fin_dict[hash] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems:

1. You are using square braces [] to define dicts instead of curly braces{}. Square brackets surround lists not dicts.
2. You are trying to use lists as keys in your second dict(fin_dict), which isn't allowed. Try referencing the second element of your comb_dict values as unique keys in fin_dict:

   ```
   comb_dict = {'1d812hjbsa' : ['Apple', 'iPad'], '190usdnb1' : ['Amazon', 'Kindle'], 'sjdb1892':['Apple', 'iPad'], '23ub8wh12' : ['Apple', 'iPhone'], '12ndsi01' : ['Amazon', 'Kindle'] }

   fin_dict={'iPad': 0, 'Kindle' : 0, 'iPhone' : 0}

   for key, value in comb_dict.items():
       if value[1] in fin_dict:
           fin_dict[value[1]] +=1
       else:
           print("unsupported device") # or exception handling
   ```